# Defining a table column to have Hex numbers only

Tags: java, swing, jtable, hex, tablecellrenderer

I have a JTable with number of columns.
I'm interested to have one of the columns to accept hexadecimal numbers only.
The format of the numbers would be:
0x[0-9a-fA-F]*

How can i create it?
If i can add an "error" indication would be great

Comment: [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
boolean isValidHex(String s) {
        return s.matches("0x[0-9a-fA-F]*");
}

void addNumberToColumn(int number) {
    String s = "0x" + Integer.toHexString(number);
    if (isValidHex(s)) {
        // accept/add to column
    } else {
        // produce error/show error message
    }
}
```

It would be great, if you could provide your code, so that your question would be clearer for the community.

**EDIT:**
OK, if I understand aright, you use the

> [TableDemo.java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TableDemoProject/src/components/TableDemo.java)

and you just want to validate the user input, so that he can enter either a HEX-formatted number or nothing (or rather it should show an error).
Hex-Integers can be represented just as Strings, so first of all, you have to change the `data` array to tell to your `TableModel` you are going to use Strings (but not Integers) in the "# of Years"-column:

```
private Object[][] data = {
            {"Kathy", "Smith",
                "Snowboarding", "5", new Boolean(false)}, // or new String("5") if you want :)
            {"John", "Doe",
                "Rowing", "3", new Boolean(true)},
            {"Sue", "Black",
                "Knitting", "2", new Boolean(false)},
            {"Jane", "White",
                "Speed reading", "2", new Boolean(true)},
            {"Joe", "Brown",
                "Pool", "10", new Boolean(false)}
};
```

The next step is to modify the `setValueAt()` method:

```
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
    if (DEBUG) {
        System.out.println("Setting value at " + row + "," + col
                + " to " + value
                + " (an instance of "
                + value.getClass() + ")");
    }

    if (col == 3) { // num of Years column
        boolean isValidHex = ((String) value).matches("0x[0-9a-fA-F]*");
        if (isValidHex) {
            data[row][col] = value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
        } else {
            data[row][col] = "Error: Wrong format!";
        }
    } else {
        data[row][col] = value;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }

    if (DEBUG) {
        System.out.println("New value of data:");
        printDebugData();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have any special code, my code is based on this example https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data I want to change "# of Years" to represent a HEX number

Comment: Ok, now its more understandable :) I've edited my answer for your question using the TableDemo.java. The code may look dirty, but I hope you have an idea now and you can adjust it for your needs.

Comment: @Kamil.Khoury did it help you?

Comment: Partially, i used your code to implement a HexIntegerCellEditor and assigned it to the column i needed. i put your implementation in stopCellEditing().  Thank you